# Why does my AWS SNS Endpoint become disabled after attempting to send a push notification to my SwiftUI-based iOS app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, swiftui, amazon-sns

I am attempting to send a push notification from SNS to my SwiftUI-based iOS App. I created a Platform Application in SNS, choosing 'token' for my authentication method, and then providing a .p8 file signing key. This worked fine. I then retrieved my a device token using

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
    };

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
       print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.banner, .badge, .sound])
    }
}
func requestPushAuthorization() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
        if success {
            print("Push notifications allowed")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                registerForNotifications()
            }
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

func registerForNotifications() {
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

where `requestPushAuthorization()` runs on init. This seemed to work and gave me a device token. I then used this device token to create an application endpoint in SNS. I then attempted to publish a message to this endpoint. It appears to succeed and even displayed

```
Message published to endpoint arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:417990662395:endpoint/APNS/Demo-Project/d818f91f-386b-364a-a426-690c86953f53 successfully.
Message "ID": 16bc460d-4472-5dec-b276-1ae4e658a2ee
Request "ID": 2bd84f94-2804-53bc-b143-137d8a2eacbe
```

However, I received no push notification on my device and when I reload SNS, the endpoint is listed as Disabled.

I am able to renable the endpoint but every time I attempt to send a message it reverts back to disabled.

I believe that this means the endpoint is invalid but I do not know the cause nor how to fix it.

And help would be appreciated!